# can a gabor filter be used for bite mark analysis?

Tags: image, image-processing

Well [bite mark analysis](http://science.howstuffworks.com/forensic-dentistry3.htm) is used in forensics to catch hold of the killer

I have an idea say i have two images

1. [image: images]

> ```
> killer's teeth impression
> ```

2. [image]

> Bite marks on the victim

How can i make sure that these two images are the same? any algorithm for this will GABOR filter suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should extract contours on both images (with Canny Edge Detector, for instance). Then, extract SIFT interest point descriptor. Then, match the images with RANSAC.

Maybe there are simpler way in your case, though...

Comment: i have studied gabor filter and it has widespread applications in fingerprint detection, palm print detection and texture analysis so figured why not in this case?

Comment: Gabor filters cannot be used directly to solve such problem, it can only be one element of a more complex system. To compare, you should tell how you want to use gabor filters.

Comment: yes that's just what i wanted to know.. am trying to find what can be done to solve my problem ..research is basically what i intend to do so thanks :)